# I only wish to schedule a refresh of some of my data. Is this possible?

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-datasource

Some of my data tables are huge and the data never changes (50 million rows+).  And some is quite small and needs regular refreshing.  How do I handle this in PowerBI?
Any ideas?

Comment: You can refresh individual queries in PowerBI Desktop, right click on table name -> refresh data.

Comment: But is it possible to do this with automatic refresh on the PowerBI Service?   I'm going to be hosting my reports in PowerBI Embedded on Azure.

Comment: Thanks. You should always post this kind of information in the question, otherwise it's vague.

Answer (score 0):

([about PowerBI Embedded](https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Developer/Power-BI-embedded-supports-data-refresh/td-p/29167)):
"***Currently direct query is all we support in terms of refresh***. Cached refresh support is certainly on our backlog as well as pushing data. As one of the previous posts suggests, you could update the file manually and re-upload it as a workaround for now.", Power BI Team

DirectQuery cannot be combined with other data sources, and it always fetches data from the source ([about directquery](https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/powerbi-desktop-use-directquery/)),

On a side note, you probably should aggregate your 50M rows, if that's possible.

Alternatively, if self hosting [PowerBI Server](https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/report-server/) is an option, you could look into moving your model to a Tabular SSAS Database, which supports [partitioning](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/analysis-services/lesson-10-create-partitions).